# How to backup data from local to remote mysql using python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, mysql-python

I have code add data to local and remote (192.168.137.1) mysql. The local and remote have same database (luan_van) and same table (tt_control) like this

```
Card_ID             Time_in           Time_out           Connect_remote
1001                 7:00              15:00                 1
1002                 8:00              19:00                 0
1003                 9:00              18:00                 0
```

Here are my subroutine:

```
def connect_remote(): # this use to check connect alive
     try:
        db = MySQLdbconnect("192.168.137.1","root_a","","luan_van")
        return 1
     except MySQLdb.OperationalError, e:
        if e[0]=2003:
            return 0
 ##### this code add data to local mysql
db_local = MySQLdbconnect("localhost","root","root","luan_van")
def add_database_local():
     x = connect_remote()
     if(x==1):
         with db_local:
             cur = db_local.cursor()
             cur.execute("INSERT INTO tt_control(card_ID.Time_in,Ket_noi) VALUES ('%d',NOW(),1)" %num)
     else:
          with db_local:
             cur = db_local.cursor()
             cur.execute("INSERT INTO tt_control(card_ID.Time_in,Ket_noi) VALUES ('%d',NOW(),0)" %num) 
     return
 ###### this code add data to remote if it alive
def add_database_remote():
    x = connect_remote()
    if(x==1):
         db = MySQLdbconnect("192.168.137.1","root_a","","luan_van")
         with db:
             cur = db.cursor()
             cur.execute("INSERT INTO tt_control(card_ID.Time_in) VALUES ('%d',NOW())" %num)
```

I want to check connect remote alive. If connect remote alive, I set column connect_remote = 1 and if connect remote die, I set column connect_remote = 0 in local tt_control table.

If remote die, I only add data to local mysql. Now if remote re-connect I want select all rows have connect_reomte =0 and send that rows to remote.

What should I do?

Comment: Why are you using Python rather than a [proper MySQL back-up strategy](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/backup-and-recovery.html)?

Comment: totally agreed with @Ben

Comment: Invalid syntax: `if e[0]=2003:` - you mean `if e[0] == 2003:`

Comment: Ben and Anzel. Because I make a project read RFID using Raspberry Pi and backup data is a part of my project.